# Two head Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines

I have this exercise

Imagine a Turing Machine that has two heads and one tape.
You need to:

1. Give a clear explanation of computation for this type of TM. Include a
   formal description of computation.

I know that a Multi-Head TM is mostly a normal TM, but i can't figure it out the explanation for that.

How does the heads work ? Each head independent or something like head1 work, finish and then the head2 start ? (Im sorry for my bad english)

Can u guys give me a hint or something ?

Comment: The head of a TM can read and write. With two heads, you could define that one head can read and the other can write but neither can do both. Or maybe both heads can do both operations but only one head is active at a time.

Comment: I suggest you "run" a simple progam with pen and paper. For example "move right, write a 1 if reading a 0, stop". How would this change when you have separate heads to read and write? Afterwards, you can abstract the general instruction changes needed for two heads.